# Easy way (transform/map ?) to create column denoting whether a corresponding field is new/old

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like :

```
Client   Date       ObjCol1   ObjCol2   NumCol1   NumCol2 
ABC     2017-06-01
ABC     2017-08-01
ABC     2017-10-01
XYZ     2018-06-01
XYZ     2019-06-01
XYZ     2019-06-01
PQR     2020-12-01
```

And i would like to create a new "entry" column to indicate if the client has got newly added for that date or is it an old one.
so it should look something like the below:

```
Client   Date       ObjCol1   ObjCol2   NumCol1   NumCol2  Entry
ABC     2017-06-01                                         New
ABC     2017-08-01                                         Old
ABC     2017-10-01                                         Old
XYZ     2018-06-01                                         New
XYZ     2019-06-01                                         Old
XYZ     2019-06-01                                         Old
PQR     2020-12-01                                         New
```

Can you advise the easy way to do this ?

Answer (score 2):

If there are sorted `Date`s per `Client` use [`Series.duplicated`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.duplicated.html) with [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['Entry'] = np.where(df['Client'].duplicated(), 'Old','New')
print (df)
  Client        Date  ObjCol1  ObjCol2  NumCol1  NumCol2 Entry
0    ABC  2017-06-01      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   New
1    ABC  2017-08-01      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   Old
2    ABC  2017-10-01      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   Old
3    XYZ  2018-06-01      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   New
4    XYZ  2019-06-01      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   Old
5    XYZ  2019-06-01      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   Old
6    PQR  2020-12-01      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   New
```

If need also sorting `datetimes` values per `Client` use:

```
df['Date']  = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])
df = df.sort_values(['Client','Date'])

df['Entry'] = np.where(df['Client'].duplicated(), 'Old','New')
print (df)
  Client       Date  ObjCol1  ObjCol2  NumCol1  NumCol2 Entry
0    ABC 2017-06-01      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   New
1    ABC 2017-08-01      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   Old
2    ABC 2017-10-01      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   Old
6    PQR 2020-12-01      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   New
3    XYZ 2018-06-01      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   New
4    XYZ 2019-06-01      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   Old
5    XYZ 2019-06-01      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   Old
```

If possible duplicated Date per groups is possible test minimal datetimes per groups:

```
df['Date']  = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'])

mask = df.groupby('Client', sort=False)['Date'].transform('min').eq(df['Date'])
df['Entry'] = np.where(mask, 'New', 'Old')
print (df)
  Client       Date  ObjCol1  ObjCol2  NumCol1  NumCol2 Entry
0    ABC 2017-06-01      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   New
1    ABC 2017-08-01      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   Old
2    ABC 2017-10-01      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   Old
3    XYZ 2018-06-01      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   New
4    XYZ 2019-06-01      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   Old
5    XYZ 2019-06-01      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   Old
6    PQR 2020-12-01      NaN      NaN      NaN      NaN   New
```